# Problem expanding ACF fields in Wordpress admin view - Console errors

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, typeerror, acfpro

I have som problems regarding Advanced Custom Fields on a site. Have tried to deactivate all other plugins but no success there.

Everything works fine on the site but in the admin view I cant expand any ACF-fields. I´ve tried to search for any related problems but cant seem to fix this.

Below you can se the errors in the console:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're missing some files or they're not registered properly. Have you tried reinstalling the ACF plugin files?

Comment: Yes, ive tried sevral versions. No success what so ever...

Answer (score 0):

So... I just added `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` into config.php and it solved the problem for now...